# Capture part of a string in sas

Tags: function, sas

Below is a string:

D:\Documents\Study\Proceeding\n_observe.txt

How do I get the following using sas function:

D:\Documents\Study\Proceeding

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So, so many ways.

Easiest is FIND and SUBSTR.

```
newstr= substr(oldstr,1,find(oldstr,'\',-1*length(oldstr))-1);
```

That uses `find`, starts at the end of the string and searches left for the first `\` to identify when to end the `substr`.

You could also use regular expressions, CALL SCAN, or even regular old scan iteratively to do the same thing.